# html form action not working when using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and Java Servlet. I was going through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnUJl3NYRRc) by Java Brains. In this tutorial get and post method is handled.

I wrote my html code under web-content.

```
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/hello" method="post">
        <input name="userName" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Following is the hello.java file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

// @WebServlet("/hello")
public class hello extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public hello() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello! from the get method " + userName);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello! From the post method " + userName);
    }
}
```

and the web.xml file is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hello</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The problem is When I run the html form under eclipse luna, instead of redirecting to http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/hello when the form is submitted, it redirects to http://localhost:8080/hello and a 404 error is shown.

If I run the html file outside eclipse it works fine. Can anyone please explain me what is the problem when running the code from eclipse?

Comment: What if you use `action="hello"` for the form tag instead of absolute url?

Comment: `action="hello"` didn't work when i first tried it. I've deleted the tomcat server and added it again. Now `action="hello"` is working. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the comment // @WebServlet("/hello"), and put  @WebServlet("/hello"). Stop the server, refresh and if its necessary clean it. And re - launch again. And take a look if the web.xml the welcome file list is correctly, because is the file which launch always.

Comment: reinstalled the tomcat server, now it's working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might add something to you.

Remove this line `@WebServlet("/hello")` or remove the servlet mapping in web.xml

Instead of using the complete URL in the form action `<form action="http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/hello" method="post">` simply use `action="hello"` that might ensure the level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/hello" method="post">
```

instead of placing absolute path in "action" use....

```
<form action="hello" method="post">
```

and restart the server hope it will help out....

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is sending form data to servlet. In servlet, you are using both GET and POST methods. But in POST method you are trying to access get parameters.

Solution:
change the form method POST to GET then it will works